# Send JSON to server not working(android)

Tags: java, php, android, json

Sorry for my english. I have activity registration, and i must send json to server if user click "registration". Before i have old prodject and then i send json like that:

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postInform = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("php string", "my value"));

try{
operationLink.makeHttpRequest(registrationURL, "POST", postInform);
}catch(Exception e) {}
```

But now i have new prodject and thet its not work. I have error from server:

```
{"message":"Customer data is empty!","status":"error"}
```

In docs server i have example:

**JSON: json registration**

```
{"company_id":"1","phones":["380000505050"],"photo":"/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629825.JPG","name":"sdfsdfdsf","birthdate":"10.02.2014","email":"sdf@sdf.ff","cars":{"1":{"car_brand_id":"9","car_model_id":"856","number":"AE5884AH","photo":"/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629824.JPG"}}}
```

And my program i create asynkTask and send data:

```
private String registrationURL = "http://crm.pavlun.info/api/register"; //working link

//code

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                JSONParser operationLink = new JSONParser();

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postInform = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company_id", "1"));
                postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phones", "380950466589"));
                postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Alexy"));
                postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birthdate", "12.03.2014"));
                postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "nesalexy@mail.ru"));
                postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", "/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629825.JPG"));

                JSONObject registration = null;

                try {
                    Log.e("perform link", postInform.toString());
                    registration = operationLink.makeHttpRequest(registrationURL, "POST", postInform);

                    Log.e("Link", registration.toString());
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
```

If i use online json send server like this http://gurujsonrpc.appspot.com/, in link i put this: `http://crm.pavlun.info/api/register` in Request JSON String i put this

```
{"company_id":"1","phones":["380034505050"],"photo":"/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629825.JPG","name":"sdfsdfdsf","birthdate":"10.02.2014","email":"sdf@sdf.ff"}
```

I have its site error **Error sending the request.** 
What i do wrong in my code???

its my `JSONParser operationLink = new JSONParser();`

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) throws JSONException {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String 
        return jObj; 
        //return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both requests example you have provided in the question and both of them  gave me the following response:

HttpStatus: 200
{"status":"error","message":"Customer data is empty!"}

So your problem is not from your side, It seems you are missing some fields and the service is throwing an error because of that although the httpStatus should not be 200.

I used Advanced Rest Client in chrome as tool to make the rest requests.